# django orm insert foreignkey via id

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a Model like

```
class Author(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, null=True, blank=True)
```

now, I have a dict in form of:

```
math = {"id": 4, "title": "math book"}
```

right now, the way im inserting data is

```
math_book = Book.objects.query(id=math['id']).first()  # im sure the value is there
author = Author.objects.first()
author.book = math_book
```

im wondering if it's possible to do something like:

```
author.book_id = math['id']
```

and save the single query to fetch the book?

Comment: Yes it's possible to provide the raw foreign key value by using the name of the ForeignKey suffixed with "_id"

Comment: fantastic, what if I needed to use something other than `id` then? would `book__<field_name>` work? or this pattern only works with id?

Comment: Only the `fk_id` property works this way, it's there for setting/getting the raw value of the field that's stored on the instance and doesn't access the other model